# Stop background-image: scrolling at its bottom position and allow text continue to scroll until finished its content

Tags: html, css

Simple code setup. Standard web page. The text content is, by scrolling the page read, of course, from the top until the bottom content is reached. The 'background-image' I have used is a portrait view showing on a letter-box PC screen and needs to be fully seen to be appreciated. Yes, positioning the 'background-position' at the top and setting 'background-attachment' to scroll accomplishes this in letting the background-image continue scrolling and fully displaying. The problem arises when it has reached its bottom view of display. The only options I am aware of are 'background-repeat' repeat or no-repeat'. I just wish to stop the 'background-image' from scrolling when it reaches its image bottom, all the while allowing the text to continue scrolling to the end of its content. An HTML answer would be optimal or/and javascript usable.

Working jpg linked stub example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content=""/>
<meta name="keywords" content=""/>
<meta name="author" content=""/>
<title>Scroll Stop Question</title>

<style>
body { 
background-color: RGB(69, 95, 135) ; 
background-image: url('https://dm2302files.storage.live.com/y4pTkvqPy2-gzOD6Taab1_kUqn1YuvTK8BKPjvtaaNRRiMTlykoSyWJ96EzLpae8g5xgcb_QfcYI5VTJnXh_2RCGyl3kATImHI40e7-RmyoRBaegjZnE6-pgJCtRjrmUYT6ReJ6THoekUWeLJXrOqpPU_KF6A7SJTmnJ2uOS6ohWOOdFQ6qweFkpDxt2vpaId-lfn5T_K7ZbacmZeMX_LHXK6-JgKt5qLQTsxIpaEiZAp4/MysticWolfandCheetah.jpg?psid=1&width=244&height=345') ; 
position: absolute ; 
z-index: -2 ; 
background-position: top center ; 
background-repeat: repeat ; 
background-attachment: scroll ; 
background-size: cover ; 
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div>
<h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1>
<h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1>
<h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1>
<h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1>
<h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1><h1>Text</h1>
</div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Please see how to create a [MRE] and update your question with the HTML and any other information we need to see the problem, so we can understand what is happening and be able to help.

Comment: Just change the background-attachment from scroll to fixed bro

Comment: Respects BUT, fixed will only hold the top (or specified) portion of the width  at  100% and lose the rest the vertical view waiting to be seen, Using fixed it does not scroll and needs to.

Comment: The question now contains a copy and paste, reproducible, jpg linked HTML stub that can easily be run to co-ordinate with the question.

Comment: `background-attachment: local` might get you some of the way there. I've not tried it. 
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment#Values]()

Comment: Thank you Simon Dell. The linked article was excellent in content. I did try your suggestion and others in variants of background properties and, unfortunately hit dead ends of no resolution. Again thanks for the communication.